# Django annotate Cannot compute Sum - is an aggregate

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, orm

I have Django ORM queryset and I am trying to perform the following

```
in_month = OrderEntry.objects.filter(order__closed_date__year=self.year).filter(
    order__closed_date__month=month_nr)
result = in_month.values('product_code').annotate(
            quantity=Sum('quantity'),
            free_count=Sum('free_count'),
            quantity_bottles=Sum(Case(
                When(product_variant__megapack_quantity=4, then=(F('quantity') * Value(4))),
                When(product_variant__megapack_quantity=None, then=F('quantity')),
                default=Value(0),
                output_field=IntegerField(),
            ))
        )
```

However, this does not work. The error I am getting :

```
Cannot compute Sum('<Case: CASE WHEN <Q: (AND: ('product_variant__megapack_quantity', 4))> THEN <CombinedExpression: F(quantity) * Value(4)>, WHEN <Q: (AND: ('product_variant__megapack_quantity', None))> THEN F(quantity), ELSE Value(0)>'): '<Case: CASE WHEN <Q: (AND: ('product_variant__megapack_quantity', 4))> THEN <CombinedExpression: F(quantity) * Value(4)>, WHEN <Q: (AND: ('product_variant__megapack_quantity', None))> THEN F(quantity), ELSE Value(0)>' is an aggregate
```

What I would like to achieve is a queryset with 4 fields:
 * product_code
 * quantity
 * free_count
 * quantity_bottles

Where quantity bottles should be calculated as follow ( in pseudo code):

```
sum = 0
for order in orders:
    if order.product_variant.megapack_quantity == 4:
        sum += order.quantity * 4
    else:
        sum += order.quantity
```

how can I fix it/achieve it with a single query to the DB with Django ORM?

Comment: You combine aggreagates over this `OrderEntry`, and over the related table, this is the main reason why it does not work. So perhaps you first want to specify *what* you want, not *how* you want it.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: I'm running into the exact same issue, but I'm not sure how to interpret your comment.